# How to get pid of Activity configured to run in distinct process?

Tags: android, process

I have an `Activity` that needs to run in a separate process (which I have named `:ChildWebView`) to workaround [an issue with `WebViewDatabase`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25507). As part of the workaround, after the `Activity` is finished, I need to kill its process. Right now, I just call `android.os.Process.myPid()` in that activity and pass the result back to the <strike>parent</strike> main process inside an `Intent`. Is there a way for the <strike>parent</strike> main process to look up the `pid` of one of its <strike>child</strike> accessory processes by name?

Comment: Killing it sounds like a bad idea.  But you could troll through /proc like the `ps` command does, looking for a process owned by your own userid and with a cmdline including what you believe it should be named.  If you have any communication between the two you might also be able to discover who the other end is from some function of the communication mechanism.  Note that the process is **not** your child (otherwise this would be easy) but rather your sibling, another child of zygote.

Comment: Does your activity, by any chance, use a service that is part of your application?  If so, I believe that you can use Binder.getCallingPid.  BTW, I'm w/Chris: this Activity sounds *really* weird.

Comment: I agree that this is weird. No, there is no service connecting to this `Activity`. I can get the pid just fine, I just assumed there would be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This didn't require any special permissions. It's pretty straightforward.

```
public void killProcessNamed(Context context, String processName) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfoList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (runningAppProcessInfoList != null) {
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcessInfoList) {
                if (runningAppProcessInfo.processName.equals(processName)) {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```